# stat not returning properly on centos 7?

Tags: c++, stat

So I am running a C++ app, built with CMake (not by me). It works fine on other people testing with it, but not found anyone to test on centos7 yet.

The issue seems to arrise at this snippet of code:

```
struct stat fileStat;
if ( stat( pszFilePath, &fileStat) == -1 )
{
    DEBUG_ERR(( "Can't open input dir [%s]\n", pszFilePath ));
    return( false );
}
```

Which is the first part of the ReadFileInfo call here:

```
time_t dateChange;
DWORD dwSize;

if ( ! CFileList::ReadFileInfo( GetFilePath(), dateChange, dwSize ))
{
    DEBUG_ERR(( "Can't get stats info for file '%s'\n", static_cast<LPCTSTR>(GetFilePath()) ));
    return false;
}
```

Now, pszFilePath is many value, a few examples are:

```
'scripts/sphere_template_vend.scp'
'scripts/sphere_serv_triggers.scp'
```

The application is owned by root, the whole folder it all sits in is owned by root. The scripts folder is there and has read/write permissions as do all files (all also owned by root)

Running the application triggers both errors in the above code, there is nothing before them that influences anything.

Im not a C++ developer and do not have the tools to compile with debugs for checking the current path and so on, but I see no reason why it throws these errors. The files exist, the files are accessible, no one else seems to have this problem.

I do have cPanel on the server, but it shouldn't be causing any issues as I am using root user and also keeping out of the /home/ directory

Anyone know of any issue this could be because of? I tried with a '/sphere/' prepending the paths but it still has the same issue, it seems the application does not have access to the files (the application oddly reports line errors within the files it says it cannot read, but they do not match, so assuming its not correct).

Issue reported on the Github for the project here: https://github.com/Sphereserver/Source/issues/64

But no one seems to know whats going on

Comment: Simply to reduce the number of variables (such as "what is the current directory when executing this?"): what happens if you use a full, explicit `pszFilePath' - that is, one starting with a slash? Does exactly the same problem occur? *This would all be for testing only, obviously.*

Comment: Yeh, still get the same error with an absolute path: 15:26:ERROR:Can't open input dir [/sphere/scripts/sphere_serv_triggers.scp]
15:26:ERROR:Can't get stats info for file '/sphere/scripts/sphere_serv_triggers.scp'

Comment: I would add `errno` (or its readable interpretation, which I'm too lazy to look up) to the first debug log.

Comment: Yeh, I would but I cant compile the thing and have little to no knowledge of how to - tried CMake but cant get it to work